# Google App Engine - How return an object to my servlet?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

Does anybody know how can I send an object, to be more specific a `List`, a result from a query in Database, to my servlet, which is another Java application and is not in Google App Engine.

---

**Update**: My servlet in GAE, is working fine, it serialize my `List<Video>` result:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {

    String titulo = req.getParameter("titulo");
    String json = "";

    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Query query = pm.newQuery("select from "+Video.class.getName()+ " where titulo.startsWith('"+titulo+"')");
    List<Video> video = (List<Video>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();

    json = new Gson().toJson(video);
    System.out.println("SERIALIZED >> " + json);

    res.setContentType("application/json");
    res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    res.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

My calling servlet has this method:

```
public void receberMetaDados(String titulo) throws IOException, Exception{
    InputStream input = new URL("http://localhost:8888/serve?titulo="+titulo).openStream();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
    List<Video> results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<Video>>(){}.getType());
}
```

I get the following exception:

> com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@2d7440 failed to deserialized json object [{"id":"30102010113847691504","titulo":"CIty of Angel","descricao":"Um belo filme","date":"30/11/2010 13:38:47"},{"id":"30102010115514196289","titulo":"CIty of Angel","descricao":"Um belo filme","date":"30/11/2010 13:55:14"},{"id":"3010201011561620697","titulo":"CIty of Angel","descricao":"Um belo filme","date":"30/11/2010 13:56:01"},{"id":"3010201012829669834","titulo":"CIty of Angel","descricao":"Um belo filme","date":"30/11/2010 14:08:29"},{"id":"3010201012849669427","titulo":"CIty of Angel","descricao":"Um belo filme","date":"30/11/2010 14:08:49"},{"id":"3010201012919920893","titulo":"CIty of Angel","descricao":"Um belo filme","date":"30/11/2010 14:09:19"}] given the type java.util.List
>       at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.deserialize(JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.java:63)
>       at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.invokeCustomDeserializer(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:88)
>       at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.visitUsingCustomHandler(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:76)
>       at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:106)
>       at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.fromJsonArray(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:64)
>       at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.deserialize(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:49)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:568)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:515)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:484)
>       at classes.Manip.receberMetaDados(Manip.java:64)
>       at servlet.OurTube_Servlet.buscar(OurTube_Servlet.java:105)
>       at servlet.OurTube_Servlet.doPost(OurTube_Servlet.java:55)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No-args constructor for class classes.Video does not exist. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type to fix this problem.
>       at com.google.gson.MappedObjectConstructor.constructWithNoArgConstructor(MappedObjectConstructor.java:64)
>       at com.google.gson.MappedObjectConstructor.construct(MappedObjectConstructor.java:53)
>       at com.google.gson.JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.constructTarget(JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.java:40)
>       at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.getTarget(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:56)
>       at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:109)
>       at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.fromJsonObject(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:73)
>       at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.deserialize(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:51)
>       at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:548)
>       at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:510)
>       at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.deserialize(JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.java:50)
>       ... 25 more

I don't know what is wrong, thank you by your assist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends. If it is to be returned as a HTTP response on a HTTP request, then you need to convert it to a string following a specific format. The popular ones are XML and JSON. The other end has just to read the XML or JSON string in and then recreate the list based on this information.

Here's an example with JSON and [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) which is able to convert Java objects to JSON and vice versa.

The called servlet:

```
List<Result> results = someDAO.list();
String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

The calling servlet:

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://example.com/servleturl").openStream();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
List<Result> results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<Result>>(){}.getType());
```

---

**Update**: as per the exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No-args constructor for class classes.Video does not exist.

This is pretty self-explaining. Supply a default constructor.

```
public class Video {
    public Video() {
        // Always keep default c'tor alive whenever you
        // supply another c'tor in a Javabean class.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!I goona try your suggestion.

Comment: Hi,i do what you say, is working, but in my calling servlet i having this error : "The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@1b11b79 failed to deserialized json object"

This is my code in my calling servlet:
List<Video> results = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Video>>(){}.getType());


Any idea ?

Comment: Isn't there more into the trace which tells about the root cause? Anyway, ensure that `Video` class is **exactly** the same on both sides.

Comment: Here is the error that is given:
The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@2d7440 failed to deserialized json object [{"id":"30102010113847691504","titulo":"CIty of Angel","descricao":"Um belo filme","date":"30/11/2010 13:38:47"},
{"id":"3010201012919920893","titulo":"CIty of Angel","descricao":"Um belo filme","date":"30/11/2010 14:09:19"}] given the type java.util.List<classes.Video>

Comment: Yes, what is it caused by? Please look further in the stacktrace, the root causes are at the bottom. This is just trivial stacktrace interpretation. Or if you don't understand what I'm talking about, then please update your question to include the complete exception with the **entire** stacktrace, those lines starting with `at com.example.SomeClass` and so on.

Comment: Hi, i found my mistake, was not to create a constructor with no args in my class Video.
Thank you by your help!You was right dude.
Best regards,
Valter Henrique.